# Pandas dataframe merge with update data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I hawe two DataFrame:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2017-01-01','2017-01-02','2017-01-03','2017-01-04','2017-01-05'], 'value':[1,1,1,1,1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2017-01-04','2017-01-05','2017-01-06','2017-01-07','2017-01-08'], 'value':[2,2,2,2,2]})

date        value      date        value         
2017-01-01      1      2017-01-04      2
2017-01-02      1      2017-01-05      2
2017-01-03      1      2017-01-06      2
2017-01-04      1      2017-01-07      2
2017-01-05      1      2017-01-08      2
```

Need to merge **df1** and **df2** to obtain the following results:

```
date        value
2017-01-01      1
2017-01-02      1
2017-01-03      1
2017-01-04      2
2017-01-05      2
2017-01-06      2
2017-01-07      2
2017-01-08      2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) by column `date` and keep last values:

```
print (pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates('date', keep='last'))
         date  value
0  2017-01-01      1
1  2017-01-02      1
2  2017-01-03      1
0  2017-01-04      2
1  2017-01-05      2
2  2017-01-06      2
3  2017-01-07      2
4  2017-01-08      2
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the combine_first command built into pandas.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html

in this case you would do

df3 = df1.combine_first(df2)

Im not certain if it works in the case you are replacing an integer with an integer or if you need to have NaN values in place.